# How to add Calendar Web Part to Sharepoint 2013 Application Page

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-addin, calendar

I am creating a sharepoint 2013 hosted application and wish to display a calendar web part on one of the pages. Is this possible? I am aware you can display lists but cannot find any evidence of getting a calendar web part to display.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an existing calendar on your page you should be able to insert a webpart and select the existing calendar.

Comment: This is a developed application through visual studio, how do you insert a webpart through this?